# WinForms. Где лучше хранить результат запроса к справочнику?

Tags: c#, winforms

Выполняется запрос к БД. Данные отображаются в гриде. Возможна фильтрация данных. Где лучше хранить результат запроса к справочнику для дальнейшего использования?

Comment: В каком смысле «где»? В зависимости от этого ответ — в памяти, в модели, в коллекции Entity-классов, ...

Comment: В прямом смысле.Чтобы БД не дергать сотни лишних раз, где лучше хранить элементы справочника, чтобы потом без проблем после фильтрации их выводить на форме?

Comment: В такой постановке вопроса, в классе/ах модели однозначно. После запуска читаете справочники из БД в модель и пользуетесь, если конечно справочники не могут быть изменены пользователем.

Comment: Это все же справочники, поэтому справочные данные могут изменяться.

Comment: Если могут меняться, значит вам придется их обновлять. Если пользователей может быть больше одного в единицу времени - придется обновлять при каждом обращении пользователя к справочнику. Исключение - личные справочники пользователя, в которые ни кто кроме него не может вносить изменения